# "Вспышка" background-color при клике на кнопке

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

как сделать чтобы при клике на кнопке `button`
background элемента `<div id="div1" class="div1"></div>`
плавно стал на 0.5 секунд `background-color:red;` и затем вернулся бы как было?

я даже загуглить не смог

Comment: Если чьё то решение было Вам полезно, то не забудьте отметить его, как решение (галочкой около цифры ответа)

Answer (score 3):

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  button.classList.add('b');
  setTimeout( () => {
       button.classList.remove('b');
  }, 500)
});
```

```css
.b{
    background-color: red;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
```

```html
<button>text</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо огромное!  Я немного переделал

```js
(function($) {
  $('.div1').on("click", function() {
    var elem = $('.div2');
    elem.addClass("testa");
    setTimeout(function() {
      elem.removeClass('testa');
    }, 300);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.testa {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 20px red;
  transition: background-color 100ms linear, box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2" class="div2">div2</div>
```

Вот только не пойму почему `background-color` применяется не так плавно как `box-shadow` :(

Comment: Потому что,  `transition` должен быть один и его значения задаются через запятую.... А в твоем случае, ты его перезаписывал, так как срабатывает с `css` последнее правило

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с плавным изменением на jquery

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="div1">Кнопка</div>

<script>(function($) {
        $('div').on("click", function(){
            var elem = $(this);
            elem.css('background', 'red');
            elem.css('transition-property', 'background-color');
            elem.css('transition-duration', '1s');
            setTimeout(function(){
                elem.css('background', '');
            }, 500);
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```